# C++ custom class limited functionality

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013, header-files

Let's say I have a custom class defined, there's a function inside the class that I want to use if and only if another header file is defined in main application.

In another words: I do not want to use certain functionality from custom defined class unless a special header file is included in main application.

If I would have my custom class definition inside main app. then I would use `#ifdef _SOME_STUFF_H` and `#endif`. This doesn't work inside header file (why would it I guess?).

The question itself: am I trying to achieve something that is a complete non-sense and should simply include all required headers?

Apologies if problem does not sound completely clear.

Code example of class (assuming class is defined in main app.):

```
class someClass
{
public:
    void doThis();

    #ifdef _SOME_HEADER_H
    //uses stuff from some_header.h
    void doThat();
    #endif
};

void someClass::doThis()
{}

#ifdef _SOME_HEADER_H
//uses stuff from some_header.h
void someClass::doThat()
{}
#endif
```

Compilies and works fine, etc.

In case we separate class to header and source we would include someClass in main.

If I would build the solution when custom class is in the main app. it would compile whether some_stuff.h is included or not (as it should).
If I would build it the other way (not including some_stuff.h in custom-class header but including it in main app.) it gives "unresolved external symbol".

Comment: post simplified code that shows the problem please

Comment: Using `#ifdef _SOME_STUFF_H` `#endif` is exactly right and works fine. Except you will violate the ODR (one definition rule) and end up in UB land. Show an example where it does not work.

Comment: Having the interface changed based on context does seem like a pretty crazy thing to do. Why isn't the interface consistent regardless of how it's imported? Either it implements a particular method or it doesn't. You're going to confuse the compiler which is going to be trying to validate that all methods declared are implemented, and all implemented methods are properly declared.

Comment: @tadman, that's pretty much the answer to the question. So I should keep it consistent and include all required headers to the custom-class headers and avoid making "if resource available" then turn this on and this off. The actual reason I was interested in the question is because it's done by author here: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/17_mouse_events/index.php

Comment: Normally you'll wall off particular methods in *both* the implementation file and the header file if you're faced with a case where it's not necessary on certain platforms or when configured in a certain way. This is usually driven by a `#define` introduced at the compiler level, globally, not because of including any particular header file first. For example something akin to `#ifdef __USE_WIN32_API` or `#ifdef __USE_LIBPNG` would be reasonable. Setting it up so the header file changes depending on context in the same build environment leads to nothing but chaos.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying things, can't mark comments as answers though

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume `#ifdef` wouldn't work? Header files aren't special; they're just source code, preprocessed and compiled like anything else. Just make sure your headers are organized with respect to their dependencies, i.e. if A.h depends on B.h, then B.h needs to be included first. But that applies regardless.